# txt = "".join([c for c in txt if c not in string.punctuation]) and TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python

A bit of a strange one. I've got a number of excel files with over half a million data points in each. Some files I can remove stopwords and conduct lemmatization, the majority of the files get the following error

```
txt = "".join([c for c in txt if c not in string.punctuation])
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Any help appreciated

```
import nltk
wn = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
ps = nltk.PorterStemmer()
dir(wn)

import pandas as pd
import re
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
pd.set_option ("display.max_colwidth", 200)
stop_word = set(stopwords.words("english"))
excel_path = (r"C:xxxx-BTC 21-30-4.xlsx")
data = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
data.columns = ["#","id", "date","Name","text_4"]


#clean text

def clean_text(txt) :
   txt = "".join([c for c in txt if c not in string.punctuation])
   tokens = re.split('\W+',txt)
   txt = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop_word]
   return txt

    data['text_5'] = data['text_4'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
    #print(data.head)
#lemmatization

def lemmatization(tolken_txt):
    text = [wn.lemmatize(word) for word in tolken_txt]
    return text
data["text_6"] = data['text_5'].apply(lambda x: lemmatization(x))

print(data.head)
```

Comment: Seems that `data['text_4']` contains numbers. `apply` transform each number separately resulting in `txt` being a float. So `clean_text` will be called by one single float number instead of a list of strings.

Comment: What is the dtype of text_4?

Comment: Hi; there are no numbers. The data types are as follows   0   #  non-null  int64
 1   id    non-null  float64
 2   date non-null  datetime64[ns]
 3   Name  non-null  object
 4   text_4   non-null  object

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you're sure that there is no float in the column `data['text_4']`, you may have missing values that can't be interable. Try droping or fillna by "". Good luck.

Comment: tried both, no joy

Comment: Hi All, Thank you all for providing responses. The issues are now resolved. The issue wasn't with numbers, it was with blank cells not being recongnised during the precleaning process. The precleaning process included use of power query to remove blank cells. using Go to special in Find and select and cleaning with python. As said in my post, some files cleaned okay some didn't.  Once again thanks.